# Problems with distinct in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Okay, i've been trying it for a while and haven't succeeded yet, it's kind of mystical, so please help.

[image: vehicle table]

Here is my table. I need to select all distinct models and group/order them by the vehicle_type. Everything is ok until I start using DISTINCT.
I'm using postgres
Little help with query please?

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: Show us some SQL that you tried and also why it doesn't work

Comment: Please provide a sample of the output you are looking for

Comment: I think the homework tag should be added.

Comment: Oh sorry i haven't described the main problem) Which is the vehicle_type values: sm_car, med_car, lge_car and sm_van, med_van, lge_van.  So i don't know how to group "cars" and "vans" separately.

Comment: according to your table diagram, vehicle_type is an integer... how could the values be sm_car, med_car, lge_car etc.? Please clarify your question. I doubt that we will be able to guess what you are asking without further information. Example entries from your table and a table of expected query output would be great.

Comment: Sorry - wrong picture. So the table - CREATE TABLE vehicle (
 vehicle_reg varchar(8) primary key,
 vehicle_type varchar(16),
 model varchar(64)
);   vehicle_type values: sm_car, med_car, lge_car and sm_van, med_van, lge_van.   I'm looking for a query to select models in such sequence : sm_car, med_car, lge_car, sm_van, med_van, lge_van. I'm trying a query like ***select distinct model, vehicle_type from vehicle group  by case when vehicle_type like '%car' then 1 when vehicle_type like '%van' then 2 end;*** but it is not working out - it gives an error

Comment: Your question seems to be lacking details. Please update it with more exact table structure(s) and add some sample data and the expected result based on those data.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming model could be shared between several vehicle types:

```
SELECT vehicle_type,model 
FROM vehicle 
GROUP BY vehicle_type,model 
ORDER BY vehicle_type,model
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment... perhaps it got truncated?

Comment: Oh sorry i haven't described the main problem) Which is the vehicle_type values: sm_car, med_car, lge_car and sm_van, med_van, lge_van. So i don't know how to group "cars" and "vans" separately

Answer (score 1):

The data model does not adequately capture your reporting requirments as the column data needs to be inspected to categorise it but something like:
(Extrapolating a possible relationship from your description)

```
SELECT CASE (vt.description ~ 'car$') 
       WHEN TRUE THEN 'car'
                 ELSE 'van' 
       END AS vehicle_group,
       vt.description AS vehicle_sub_group,
       COUNT (*) -- or whatever aggregates you might need
  FROM vehicle v
       INNER JOIN vehicle_type vt ON vt.vehicle_type = v.vehicle_type
 GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Might get you towards what you need in the stated case, however it is a fragile way of dealing with data and will not cope well with additional complexities e.g. if you need to further split car into saloon car, sports car, 4WD or van into flatbed, 7.5 ton, 15 ton etc.

Comment: yeap, you're right, I've changed the data model so it is more flexible now